# Calcular tempo entre datas no mysql

Tags: mysql, select

Tenho uma tab ele de log com uma coluna do tipo TIMESTAMP que grava o horário de login e logout do usuário. Preciso de um `select` que compare o horário do login e logout do usuário para calcular o tempo que o mesmo ficou conectado.

Parece simples, mas não estou avançando.

Comment: Pode mostar o select que já fez?

Comment: Nelson, boa tarde.

Comment: Nelson, o problema é que tenho várias entradas e saídas do usuário durante o dia, precisaria alinhar cada t.login com seu t.logout subsequente para a query rodar e calcular a diferença de tempo entre login e logout.

Comment: Cara o que  você poderia fazer é usar o SUM(),   junto com aqueles exemplos ali e ai não clausula where você coloca mais um and data = now() ai é para resolver

Answer (score 5):

Você pode já tentou usar o TIMESTAMPDIFF(unit, datetime1, datetime2)? Ele retorna a subtração de datetime2- datetime1 e a unit pode ser SECOND, MINUTE, HOUR, DAY, WEEK, MONTH, QUARTER, ou YEAR

segue sintaxe:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,'2009-05-18','2009-07-29');
```

irá retornar 2

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,'2003-02-01','2003-05-01 12:05:55');
```

irá retornar 128885, ou no seu caso

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, t.login, t.logout)
from tabela t 
where user_id = id_do_usuario;
```

isso retornará em minutos o tempo ai é só tratar ou daria para retornar já na consulta também:

```
 SELECT CONCAT(FLOOR(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, t.login, t.logout) /60), 'hr', MOD(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, t.login, t.logout), 60),'m') as tempo_logado 
 from tabela t where user_id = id_do_usuario;
```

Referência: [MySQL 5.5 Reference Manual  /  Functions and Operators  /  Date and Time Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Espero ter ajudado.